# Syntax error when loading from file

Tags: sqlite

I execute: `sqlite3 -init mydata.sql mydb` with the following as the only line in mydata.sql:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [Album];
```

I get the following error:

> Error: near line 1: near "∩╗┐DROP": syntax error

I've whittled the input file to virtually nothing and I always get this syntax error message no matter what command I enter and always on line 1. It looks like it thinks there's some unusual character but I can's see what it could be. Any thoughts?

Comment: How are you saving the file? What's the encoding?

Comment: @tripleee Good call.  My SQL script was in UTF-8 and no unexpected unprintable characters were showing up (see harsh's answer) but I was still getting the error until I changed the encoding to UTF-8 without the byte order mark.

Answer (score 6):

If you use Notepad++ or other similar text editor, enable showing all symbol.

In Notepad++, view->show symbol->Show All characters

Also check Encoding of this file (Menu->Encoding). You might want to forcefully change encoding to ANSI/UTF-8 (Menu->Encoding->Convert to ANSI).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error with the `Chinook` database and `SQLite` version 3.19.3, so I opened the SQL file (`Chinook_Sqlite_AutoIncrementPKs.sql`) with `Sublime Text` and save it like UTF-8 (to eliminate the BOM indicator).